# Numbers of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Numbers of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$. I read "On the number of subgroups of a given exponent in a finite abelian group" and the author give us next formula:

> The total number $s(m, n)$ of subgroups of the group $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ is
>
> $s(m,n)=\sum_{i|m,j|n}{ \gcd(i,j)}$

I dont understand the meaning of $i|m,j|n$ in the formula. There is an example were $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{18}$ and $s(12,18)=80$.
How I can apply this formula?

Comment: $i|m$ means $i$ is a (positive) divisor of $m.$ E.g. if $m=6$ then $i=1,2,3,6.$

Comment: $m\;|\;n$ means "$m$ (evenly) divides $n$", so in total it probably means "sum over all $i$ that divide $m$ and $j$ that divide $n$"? So for $m =12$ you'd have $1,2,3,4,6,12$, for $n=18$ you'd have $1,2,3,6,9,18$. Now make all pairs of that and sum up their $\text{gcd}$s and see if that equals $80$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the sum has to be interpreted as a doube-sum. $i|m$ in the subscript of the $\Sigma$ means summation over all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ which divide the number $m$. Notice that there will always be a finite number of these $i$s. The same goes for $j$. So, if we rewrite that more clearly it would say

$$s(m,n)= \sum_{i | m} \sum_{j | n} \text{gcd}(i,j)$$
or
$$s(m,n)= \sum_{\text{all divisors of }m \text{ as }i}\; \sum_{\text{all divisors of } n \text{ as }j} \text{gcd}(i,j)$$

Or, expressed more clearly in code with using the example numbers of $m=12$, $n=18$, and their respective set of divisors ($1,2,3,4,6,12$ for $m=12$ and $1,2,3,6,9,18$ for $n=18$):

[image]

And you can also see that that sum equals 80, as your book says.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!!! It help me so much!!!